# Rails ActiveRecord How to make foreign key in second table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Simple question: How can I make 'rateable_id' my foreign key for bboys table?

db schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140331112614) do

  create_table "bboys", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "crew"
    t.string   "country"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "rates", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "rater_id"
    t.integer  "rateable_id"
    t.string   "rateable_type"
    t.float    "stars",         null: false
    t.string   "dimension"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to read some tutorial before implementing anything. People don't like to answer questions those are not built correctly and supported with some basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the gem [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner), probably it can help you. I don't know what exactly you want. Try to write more description about your question.